# UIWebView - how to find the length

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I need to know the length of a the output in an UIWebView (in whatever units).
Is this possible? Internally IOS must know this to control the scrolling but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: what do you mean by "length"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by length, you mean the height of the content, you can use one of the following in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:`delegate method:

```
CGFloat height01 = [[[webView subviews] lastObject] contentSize].height;
CGFloat height02 = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height;
CGFloat height03 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
```

They should return the same value.

Comment: Apologies, I have been trying to get this to work without any joy hence the delay in repaying. This is an area of xcode that I'm unfamiliar with. If my webview is called, say, myWebView does the delegate first line read...- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView{ and do I need a following line like  CGRect frame = myWebView.frame; ? Against your CGSize lines I'm getting yellow Local declaration of myWebView hides instance variable. Can you advise further. I'm sure you're right.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't quite understand your comment. But I spotted an error in my answer that I corrected. It is not a `CGSize` but a float that is extracted. Once you have the float you can do whatever you required the height for (e.g. update a scrollview's `contenSize` property).

Comment: If you named your webview  `myWebView`, to prevent the `local declaration hides instance variable`warning, change the delegate callback to something like: `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {...}` ('myWebView' <> 'webView')

Comment: Hmm? Cleaned up the code but this delegate doesn't seem to be being executed: '- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{'

Comment: Did you set the delegate? In `viewDidLoad`add `myWebView.delegate = self;`

Comment: That's it, and yes they DO all return the same values :-) Very many thanks.